# c++ passing a vectored class to another class

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to write my code without using global variable as most people told me it was a bad habit, so I am changing how my program works.

I am having problem with passing multiple instance of a class to another class. I need to be able to modify the multiple instance of a class in the other class.

Here is what I am trying to do but failing miserably at it :

```
int main() {
Players *player[6];

//preparing 6 instances of Players() so I can loop through them in another class
for (int i = 0;i<6;i++){
player[i] = new Players();
}
player[0]->name = "fluffy";
```

Players.h

```
#ifndef PLAYERS_H_
#define PLAYERS_H_
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Players {
public:
    Players();
    virtual ~Players();
    std::string name;
    bool hand;
    int cif;
    int id;
    std::vector<int> autho;
    std::vector<int> collec;
    std::vector < std::vector <int> > puppet;
};
#endif /* PLAYERS_H_ */
```

Players.cpp

```
#include "Players.h"
Players::Players() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    name = "";
    hand = false;
    cif = -1;
    id = -1;
}

Players::~Players() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Now I want to call another class (doesn't matter which) and I want to pass the multi instanced class Players to it so it can read and do modification to the data within these instanced classes.

For example a class with a function that could read player[0]->name and modify it to "sandpaper"

How would you approach this without getting errors from the compiler?

I am open to suggestion for a completely different way to approach this ( I have tried to use struct variables and pass it but I got other problems as well)

thank you,
Kaven

Comment: Show your code and the error you're getting.

Comment: Could you please add error text into your question?

Comment: What is your "another class", and its method that you want to passed your multiple instance into? Show the code of that.

Comment: As the others told you, provide more infos. some additional points: you use a modern construct like a vector, but you store your players class instances within an array? `name = ""` is the same behavior as the string ctor will do automatically. use encapsulation, never give direct access to your members.

Comment: On the subject of bad habits, you might also want to consider not using public variables in your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to approach like this:

```
int main() 
{
unique_ptr<vector<Player>> playersVector (new vector<Player>);

    for (int i = 0;i<6;i++)
    {
        playersVector->push_back(Players());
    }
    playersVector->at(0).name = "fluffy";
}
```

And then if you want to pass that vector with ownership to some method or class use:

```
move(playersVector)
```

If you want have ownership in main class pass by normal pointer:

```
playersVector.get()
```

I also suggest using Get/Set methods instead of accessing class fields directly

Comment: You know, that the OP had an array of pointers to player and you have a pointer to an array / vector of players? Not saying this is wrong, just wondering if that is on purpose?

Comment: I just proposed one of the possibility. OP did't specify conditions how exactly he want to deal with problem so I just provided one of the possible solutions. But as you mentioned my proposal differs from OP one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd approach this by using `std::vector<Players>` (not pointers!). Secondly, I'd just pass this vector **by reference** to other functions.